# How would I go about Game Networking with C#?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, dll

So, I'm trying and put my C# skills to the test, I have set myself towards making a Game with Networking in C#. This Game will not have movement (It's a hacking sim, so I don't think data will need to be constantly sent) what do you Guys think would be the best .dll or way to go about this? What about the Database for accounts? What do you think I could use? I have a average skill level in C#, so keep that in mind when making recommendations, please.

Comment: Sounds like you're a bit out of your depth.  The method you should use is not relevant to your skill level.  Why are the built in `Socket` or `TCPClient` classes not good enough?

Comment: @LukePark
I have had issue with allocating were things should go with them (For Example, a Client sends the Server data, the Server does whatever with it, and say the Server wants to send that data back, and multiple clients are connected, how would the server know who to send it to?)

Comment: The server would send it to the `Socket` that it received the data on...  This is quite a trivial problem.  Look up "Server Multithreading".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have average skill using an SDK should be helpful for you.

Start out with something like XNA Game Studio to see how those concepts are done.

This document is the starting point for the SDK https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx and the "Network" concepts you are specially looking for are discussed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975947.aspx

As for the database for accounts, this would be no different than any typical application that accesses a database and stores user accounts.

Comment: Be wary.  The network solution provided is for use on Xbox systems only.

Comment: @LukePark, I agreed. that's why I said "see how those concepts are done" to provide some kind of general knowledge on the topic. I agree with you that this topic may be a little out of their depths.